# Completely stuck trying to use Abraham Williams Twitter API libraries

Tags: php, api, twitter

I’m working through Sam’s Teach Yourself Twitter API.. In Hour 8, there are simple instructions of setting up the consumer key, consumer secret (I already had a different php program using these succesfully) and using Abraham Williams libraries. I plugged the key,secret into config.php, used the define(’OAUTH_CALLBACK’, ‘http://localhost/callback.php’); with localhost and created a tinyurl for it (the work around if localhost doesnt work. Get the sign in to Twitter screen and then it goes to the redirect page that says:

“Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.”

I’m completely dead in the water here. Once I get this working, I’ll be off and running, but I’m completely stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

(In reponse to your questions:)

They have a config.php file where they say to put in the KEY and SECRET, which I've done:

```
define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'KEY');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'SECRET');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://localhost:8888/abeoauth/connect.php');
```

They book says to run index.php. Here's code from that:

```
/* Load required lib files. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

/* If access tokens are not available redirect to connect page. */
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) ||     empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
    header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,     $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

/* If method is set change API call made. Test is called by default. */
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

Starting at index.php, like the book says, it does redirect to the "connect.php" page so it's as if I've put nothing in for the KEY variables at all..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as a result here? Just to establish a connection or pull data from twitter?

Comment: What is your current code? What have you tried?

Comment: I added code in the top to respond to your question

Comment: David, at this point I'm just trying to get a connection so I can try out the examples in the book. Goes on to make tweets, direct messages, get list of people from your friends list, etc, etc

Comment: Doesn't appear to be getting the temporary credentials correctly

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. Looks like it didn't like the "twitter application"(credentials) that I'd created for a different script (that worked btw). I had to create a new one just for this book example.